# Popup on image rollover

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a series of small images (24x24) indicating various system statuses. When a user rolls over of the images (e.g. a system alert image) I want a popup to display the first 5 alerts and a *More...* option (if there are more than 5 alerts). While the list is displayed, I want the user to be able to select one of the alerts or the *More* option and display the details.

The problem I am having is:

I cannot prevent the popup from disappearing when the mouse leaves the image to select an item.

Here is a segment of XAML from my User Control I am using to display the popup.

```
 <Image x:Name="SmallImage"
               Source="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ImageSource}"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Height}"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Width}"
               Grid.Row="0" />
        <Popup Name="ItemPopup"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               PopupAnimation="Fade"
               HorizontalOffset="-35"
               VerticalOffset="0"
               Grid.Row="1">
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SmallImage, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                              <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />

                           </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
            <Border x:Name="MyBorder" BorderBrush="#72777F" Background="White" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="This is your list of items."></Label>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `Trigger` will fire everytime the `IsMouseOver` Property will change and in case `Trigger` condition fails it will set the `Property` to its default i.e false in this case. You will need two `Triggers` here, one for opening the popup in case of `IsMouseOver` is true and second is to keep popup open if `IsMouseOver` becomes false and `Popup` was already open.

```
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SmallImage, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=SmallImage, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: This will behave the same as the Trigger he already has, if he moves the mouse of the image IsMouseOver will become false and set IsOpen to False.

Comment: you are absolutely correct.. dont know what i was thinking..:) so there is a need of two triggers as in my updated answer

Comment: This did answer my question, however, there were other issue I ran into with trying to get the popup to close and re-show. I used event handlers to set the IsOpen property.